# How do you update SignalR-Objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, signalr, cocoapods

I'm very new to iOS/Objective C development, so this is very probably a very easy question to answer.  I'm building a project whih uses the SignalR-ObjC library, which is an Objective C implementation of SignalR.

To download and install the library, the SignalR-ObjC website says to use Cocoapods, which I have duly done.  However the version of SignalR-ObjC available over Cocoapods is not the most recent version, and there's a more recent version on GitHub.  I need to use the latest version as I'm told that there are some bugs in the old version, and I want to use some of the more recently added features.

I've tried as couple of ways of updating the SignalR-ObjC library, but can't quite seem to get it right.

For an iOS ObjectiveC project which uses libraries downloaded through Cocoapods, how do I update one of the Cocoapods libraries with code downloaded from GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

You can write 'SignalR-ObjC', '2.0.0.beta3' to your Podfile. This will download the latest SignalR library and subsidiary libraries that are needed to run the library.